Computations of vanishing ideals
I want to compute the following vanishing ideal:
For $V=V(x^2+y^2-1)\cap V(x-y)$ in the setting of $k[x,y]$ where $k$ is algebraically closed.
So we want to know $I(V(x^2+y^2-1)\cap V(x-y))$.
We can do this computation with basic properties and the Nullstellensatz.
$I(V(x^2+y^2-1)\cap V(x-y))=I(V(x^2+y^2-1, x-y))=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2-1, x-y)}$.
Doing some computations, we can find that $2y^2-1\in (x^2+y^2-1, x-y)$. I know looking up the theory of Gröbner Basis that $(2y^2-1, x-y)$ generates the ideal we take the radical of. It does not seem that we can simplify any further.
Is there an approach that does not use Gröbner Basis? Can we say more about this vanishing ideal?
Do you know an online tool that can compute radical ideals?
Thank you.

Regarding online tools for radical ideals: See here: https://macaulay2.com/TryItOut/

Please do not answer in the comments.

@Shaun Just deleting the comments is just disrespectful. If you want them as an answer, save them as an answer.

If the characteristic of $k$ is $2$, then $\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb{V}} x^2 + y^2 - 1 = (x+y+1)^2$, so
\begin{align*}
\V(x^2 + y^2 - 1) = \V((x+y+1)^2) = \V(x+y+1) \, .
\end{align*}
Then
$$
V = \V(x+y+1) \cap \V(x+y) = \varnothing \, ,
$$
so $\newcommand{\I}{\mathbb{I}} \I(V) = k[x,y]$.
If the characteristic is not $2$, then
\begin{align*}
2y^2-1 = x^2 + y^2 - 1 - (x+y)(x-y) \in (x^2+y^2-1, x-y)
\end{align*}
as you mentioned, and we have $(x^2+y^2-1, x-y) = (2y^2 - 1, x-y)$. Then
\begin{align*}
(x^2+y^2-1, x-y) &= (2y^2 - 1, x-y) = (y^2 - 1/2, x-y)\\
&= ((y-1/\sqrt{2})(y+1/\sqrt{2}), x-y)\\
&= (y-1/\sqrt{2}, x-y)(y+1/\sqrt{2}, x-y)\\
&= (x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2})(x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2}) \, .
\end{align*}
Since
\begin{align*}
1 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left(y-1/\sqrt{2}\right) - \left(y+1/\sqrt{2}\right) \right) \in (x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2}) + (x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2}) \, ,
\end{align*}
then $(x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2}) + (x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2}) = k[x,y]$. The product of comaximal ideals is equal to their intersection (see here or here), so
\begin{align*}
(x^2+y^2-1, x-y) &= (x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2})(x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2})\\
&= (x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2}) \cap (x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2}) \, .
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
\V(x^2+y^2-1, x-y) &= \V\left((x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2}) \cap (x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2})\right)\\
&= \V\left((x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2})\right) \cup \V\left(x+1/\sqrt{2}, y+1/\sqrt{2})\right)\\
&=\{(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}), (-1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2})\} \, .
\end{align*}
This agrees with the intuitive geometric picture: this set is the intersection of the unit circle with the line $y=x$.

Great stuff. Thank you very much. This is extremly helpfull and enlightening. Do you have by any means similar exercises to practice on?

@MathUnicorn I think there are similar exercises in Cox, Little, and O'Shea's Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms, and also maybe in Fulton's Algebraic Curves.

Thanks, I will take a look at it.
